# Garbage disposal wiring

Tags: wiring

I've installed a new disposal on it's own 20A circuit with a wall switch, everything works fine... no problems. I was told it needs to be a GFCI receptacle. What say you?

Comment: Is the disposal hardwired, or plugged into a receptacle.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does, under 2014 code. You may find outdated articles claiming it does not - they are outdated.

210.8(A)(7)  Any 125V 15 or 20 A receptacle within 6 feet of the outside edge of a sink (shortest path) requires GFCI protection

Used to have an exception for dwelling kitchens (up to 2011) does not now (2014 forward.) Other than dwellings was required in 2008.

Comment: First, it depends on what the currently **adopted** code in the area is, not the current printed code. Second, if the disposal is hardwired, 210.8(A)(7) does not apply.

Comment: Agreed, a code is NOT "outdated" if it is the one currently in place in your location. Also, many would disagree that a receptacle located under a sink, and within a cabinet, is within 6' of the sink. Most inspectors I know would not require GFI protection.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey I agree. The wording is strange, and I'm not sure if a receptacle under the sink is any distance away from the outside edge of the sink.  In fact, following the words as written, I don't think a receptacle *inside* the sink would have to be GFCI protected.

Comment: Virtually every site reporting on changes in the 2014 code disagrees with your interpretation, but I'm neither promoting nor plagiarizing them.

Comment: I guess here's the 5th opinion from the 4th farmer, What's $12 to prevent possible water + electricity related interactions?